Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x26
----> TX     ├─ Signatures[len=1] │    └─ 4UJPHEtrmksnNrX2DemwZHkyPDsYwtNgLvezzymzULjbuRB6QSEnFwig46rTD3j3kBUw1jFnaRRVi9FTUBG1UWiP ├─ Message │    ├─ Version: legacy │    ├─ RecentBlockhash: B6D2WSyMY7oizqpa6owMKgGjJYvBtxRQ7ZFZikVifdfR │    ├─ AccountKeys[len=18] │    │    ├─ 4HuJk6uYZGy9s6DhtnfrfWwfWQC5wn1Yst3opnGhUNhy │    │    ├─ 6q8z9WAryLBviHqa8v4kBmb5q8ocd2hHCPsURKudgmew │    │    ├─ 6c8QHXj5cXurwivUND1HHZNbjSSY8EC5xhFENFZ5fmsZ │    │    ├─ HVzJiG1xNHLJAqEsoQ97MaaMMMAoiS55ZHYUMuJEP3WJ │    │    ├─ GHsnp8iphQNpoun37hsZ2bPinqHSwUcfcapWJVraKJEP │    │    ├─ pb4G12Xa5Q2buTSSsUMwMGCimxpHsnSUSVodtS1m2aX │    │    ├─ Diu1oueq563cseEYaLKXAdzeeTfML9qy9JieqHftDhbd │    │    ├─ 2EmrRzKgBvz1pbivDyNmkyQ4eZ421wwWaa9JEsSAYg3Z │    │    ├─ HkwXsG5fCCdM4pkqXTeboxjHdE8mXBofwZtbK2pPiqYX │    │    ├─ DxjAwrtoaUmrMTrHxGQzvXeVcFbFPp1wBy1cEq7pnhTX │    │    ├─ BxMtoXysGfzv8QkLThFRfguG7FtgivaL8Ahji6Uzh1v9 │    │    ├─ 2Kw6sdPWn758dYxobo8th67vYzipA4nCgR5uVaAUARH1 │    │    ├─ 4Tu7ne3XDjkQhnPvu5mG49q7T6v7VxzaUqFLdowmYv7A │    │    ├─ TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA │    │    ├─ 5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1 │    │    ├─ srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX │    │    ├─ DmiCMQpRELBiueaNK6CeKBieLqixTjqwvhc8hWUqjU5S │    │    └─ 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 │    └─ Header │       ├─ NumRequiredSignatures: 1 │       ├─ NumReadonlySignedAccounts: 0 │       └─ NumReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 5 └─ Instructions[len=1] └─ cannot decode instruction for 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 program: instruction decoder not found └─ Program: <unknown> 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 └─ Instruction: <unknown> ├─ data[len=17 bytes] │    └─ {9, 106, 178, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 108, 74, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}(len=17) └─ accounts[len=18] ├─ accounts[0]: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA []  ├─ accounts[1]: 6q8z9WAryLBviHqa8v4kBmb5q8ocd2hHCPsURKudgmew [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[2]: 5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1 []  ├─ accounts[3]: 6c8QHXj5cXurwivUND1HHZNbjSSY8EC5xhFENFZ5fmsZ [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[4]: HVzJiG1xNHLJAqEsoQ97MaaMMMAoiS55ZHYUMuJEP3WJ [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[5]: GHsnp8iphQNpoun37hsZ2bPinqHSwUcfcapWJVraKJEP [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[6]: pb4G12Xa5Q2buTSSsUMwMGCimxpHsnSUSVodtS1m2aX [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[7]: srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX []  ├─ accounts[8]: Diu1oueq563cseEYaLKXAdzeeTfML9qy9JieqHftDhbd [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[9]: 2EmrRzKgBvz1pbivDyNmkyQ4eZ421wwWaa9JEsSAYg3Z [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[10]: HkwXsG5fCCdM4pkqXTeboxjHdE8mXBofwZtbK2pPiqYX [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[11]: DxjAwrtoaUmrMTrHxGQzvXeVcFbFPp1wBy1cEq7pnhTX [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[12]: BxMtoXysGfzv8QkLThFRfguG7FtgivaL8Ahji6Uzh1v9 [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[13]: 2Kw6sdPWn758dYxobo8th67vYzipA4nCgR5uVaAUARH1 [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[14]: DmiCMQpRELBiueaNK6CeKBieLqixTjqwvhc8hWUqjU5S []  ├─ accounts[15]: 4Tu7ne3XDjkQhnPvu5mG49q7T6v7VxzaUqFLdowmYv7A [WRITE]  ├─ accounts[16]: 4Tu7ne3XDjkQhnPvu5mG49q7T6v7VxzaUqFLdowmYv7A [WRITE]  └─ accounts[17]: 4HuJk6uYZGy9s6DhtnfrfWwfWQC5wn1Yst3opnGhUNhy [WRITE, SIGN]  
BUILDING a simple swap transaction instruction all accounts seems to be alright
`   poolKey := solana.PublicKey(bytesAddres)
poolsKey, err := raydium.FetchPoolKeys(rpcClient, poolKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error getting pool keys")
}

PoolInfo := raydium.FetchInfo(rpcClient, poolsKey)
if len(PoolInfo) > 0 {
    prettyJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(PoolInfo[0], "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling to JSON:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(prettyJSON))
    }
} else {
    fmt.Println("No pools info available.")
}
amount := 0.1 / 175.45
normalizedPrice_ := int64(float64(amount) * float64(solana.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL))
normalizedPrice := big.NewInt(normalizedPrice_)
inputToken := raydium.WSOLToken()
inputTokenAmount := raydium.NewTokenAmount(*inputToken, normalizedPrice, true)
outputToken := raydium.NewToken(poolsKey.BaseMint, poolsKey.BaseDecimals, poolsKey.ID, poolsKey.ID)
slippagePercent := raydium.NewPercent(big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(100))
minAmountOut := raydium.ComputeAmountOutSimple(poolsKey, PoolInfo[0], *inputTokenAmount, *outputToken, *slippagePercent)
wallet := solana.MustPrivateKeyFromBase58("25Q2gX2TveYtmfrHACrSSmLVoNmAeMQC2FJsBtrSKR9j7Z76auRHSp7q5rwhv75G7rCoQZ7uSN8zsVpiVujkLwMD")
walletTokenAccounts_ := raydium.GetWalletTokenAccount(*rpcClient, wallet.PublicKey())

userKeys := raydium.UserKeys{
    TokenAccounts: walletTokenAccounts_,
    Owner:         wallet.PublicKey(),
    Payer:         wallet.PublicKey(),
}
const txVersion raydium.TxVersion = 0
var computeConfig_ raydium.ComputeBudgetConfig

liquidtySwapParams := raydium.LiquiditySwapInstructionSimpleParams{
    Connection: rpcClient,
    PoolKeys:   poolsKey,
    UserKeys:   userKeys,
    AmountIn:   *inputTokenAmount,
    AmountOut:  minAmountOut,
    FixedSide:  "in",
    Config:     raydium.Config{},
}

_tokenAccountIn, _tokenAccountOut := raydium.BuildTokenAccounts(liquidtySwapParams, txVersion, raydium.CacheLTA{}, computeConfig_, rpcClient)
fmt.Printf("\nToken ACCOUNTS IN: %v \n TOKEN ACCOUNT OUT: %v\n", _tokenAccountIn, _tokenAccountOut)
instrs := []solana.Instruction{}
instructions := raydium.NewSwapInstructions(
    *inputTokenAmount,
    minAmountOut,
    raydium.MakePubKeyFromString("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"),
    raydium.MakePubKeyFromString(poolsKey.ID),
    poolsKey.Authority,
    poolsKey.OpenOrders,
    poolsKey.TargetOrders,
    poolsKey.BaseVault,
    poolsKey.QuoteVault,
    poolsKey.MarketProgramID,
    poolsKey.MarketID,
    poolsKey.MarketBids,
    poolsKey.MarketAsks,
    poolsKey.MarketEventQueue,
    poolsKey.MarketBaseVault,
    poolsKey.MarketQuoteVault,
    poolsKey.MarketAuthority,
    _tokenAccountIn,
    _tokenAccountOut,
    wallet.PublicKey(),
)
signers := []solana.PrivateKey{wallet}
instrs = append(instrs, instructions)

txns, err := raydium.BuildTransacion(context.Background(), rpcClient, signers, instrs...)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR %s\n", err)
}`

